# DataCamp Light: reuse objects across exercises

Tags: r-markdown

I would like to minimize redundancy in my R-markdown file that uses the [tutorial](https://datacamp.github.io/tutorial/) package from *DataCamp Light*. It would seem reasonable to want to reuse objects across exercises which does not work in this tiny example:

````
```{r, include=FALSE}
tutorial::go_interactive()
z = qnorm(0.99)
```

```{r ex="zQuantile_1", type="pre-exercise-code"}
z = qnorm(0.99)
```

```{r ex="zQuantile_1", type="sample-code"}
# Compute the 99% quantile of the normal distribution 
z = ___
```

```{r ex="zQuantile_1", type="solution"}
# Compute the 99% quantile of the normal distribution 
z = qnorm(0.99)
z
```

```{r ex="zQuantile_2", type="sample-code"}
# Using pnorm, verify the tail to the  right of z to be 0.01  
1-pnorm(___)
```

```{r ex="zQuantile_2", type="solution"}
# Compute the 99% quantile of the normal distribution 
1-pnorm(z)
```
````

> Error: Fail because of runtime error: object 'z' not found

Is there any way I can recycle objects that were either defined globally in the markdown or in previous exercises ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the chunk option `ref.label` to recycle code from other chunks.

In your case, you can first add a label (in this case "precode") to your second chunk:

```
{r precode, ex="zQuantile_1", type="pre-exercise-code"} 
z = qnorm(0.99)
```

Now, insert a pre-exercise code chunk for your second exercise that just calls your labeled code chunk:

`{r ex="zQuantile_2", ref.label="precode", type="pre-exercise-code"}`